# Regex in Java for "greater than" or "less than" without using bracket "<|>" symbols

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression for Java Pattern.compile("<|>") that would match greater than and less than symbols without actually using bracket symbols. Is there some special character that would mean ">" or "<" symbol?

Additional info: The reason is that my legacy system passes regular expressions from a resource file that first gets parsed using some html tags, and extra brackets confuse the parser, so it errors out. The solution is to substitute ">" and "<" with something else that Java Pattern would interpret as ">" and "<".

What I tried: Pattern.compile("&grt;") does not get interpreted as ">"

Comment: *FYI:* For choice between single characters, use a `[]` character class, i.e. use `[<>]` instead of `<|>`. This also applies to the answers below, where the `<>` characters have been replaced, e.g. use `[\u003c\u003e]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do that:

- You could write it down as ASCII ordinals, like this: `((char) 60) + "|" + ((char) 62)`;
- You could use Unicode escape sequences in the regular expression: `\\u003c|\\u003e`;
- You could use Java Unicode escape sequences, like this: `\u003c|\u003e`.

About that last point — it is seldom used, but the programmer may use Unicode escape sequences *anywhere* in the Java source code. For instance,

```
public\u0020class\u0020Main {
    public\u0020static\u0020void\u0020main(String[] args) { }
}
```

is valid Java code.

Answer (score 4):

I'm on mobile and can't run this to test, but I *believe* that you can use unicode code points to match on the brackets.  So this should work: `Pattern.compile("\\u003c|\\u003e");`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply escape those characters like:

```
Pattern.compile("\\<|\\>")
```

By using the backslashes, you are telling regex that "use that character as is!"

For more about escaping characters, see https://www.baeldung.com/java-regexp-escape-char

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, I cannot use the brackets anywhere in the regex - due to a pre-processing parser, brackets lead to errors. I need to match brackets without actually using brackets in the regex

Comment: I don't think it is possible? I guess another way to get around the pre-precessor is to put ```"\\<|\\>"``` in a variable somewhere else where the pre-precessor cannot touch, then use the variable in Pattern.compile.

I've never heard of a pre-precessor that would not allow <>

Comment: Yeah, I know, the legacy system that I use has issues. What I can change is the resource file but not the module that uses the resource file.   The pipeline design starts with a resource file that gets parsed using html tags with <> brackets and everything that is between the tags gets sent to Pattern.compile. I was really hoping that the community would suggest something like \{some numeric representation} for >

Comment: Perhaps you can construct the string out of char concatination like ```"" + ((char) 60) + "|" + ((char) 62)``` ? 60 and 62 are ascii numbers for < and >

Comment: @JClassic you don't need that first `""` in the preceding comment.